# Which automorphic L-functions have an integral representation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Is there a list of which automorphic L-functions are known to have an integral representation?

Comment: What do you mean by "known to have an integral representation?"  E.g., L(s,pi) = \int ... for some specific test function?  Unramified calculation?

Comment: Bump's 2005 survey is a good place to start: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110892703.41/html?lang=en

Comment: This is not a direct answer but there's a somewhat related list at https://www.jonathanpwang.com/notes/RelativeDualitydb.html - basically all the L-functions labeled by data on the RHS (which is *roughly* a list of reps of the dual group) have integral representations, labeled by the LHS.